# How to Give Credit for An Answer in the Comments

Tags: support, answers, etiquette, attribution

I asked a question on SO and someone gave me the answer as a comment to the question. Subsequently, someone else gave the same answer as an answer.

I would like to give credit to the poster who made the comment. Is there any way to do that?

Being new to the site, my only thought would be to contact the commenter and tell him to post an answer if he/she wants credit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this particular case, the poster of the comment didn't know what he was talking about, so he didn't want to risk posting as an answer and getting downvotes if he was wrong.

He probably doesn't care about it that much, so I advise just upvoting and/or accepting the answer you got in the answer section.

Comment: +1, this is the sort of behavior Joel imagined when SO launched

Comment: Actually, the poster of the comment had the right answer and the person posting the answer basically repeated what he/she had said. Also, the posted answer was after I responded to the commenter that he/she had solved my problem.  No big deal, just want to give credit where credit is due.

Comment: I know, but the commenter posted in the comments because he didn't want credit. Voting and especially accepting answers is not just for credit, it's also to mark that your problem has been solved to the system.