# Unanswered Question - Answered in comments

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, comment-replies

I am relatively new to SO and see this very often. As the title suggests there are many questions that are answered in comments itself and they remain unanswered forever. Shouldn't there be an option to mark a comment as an answer and the comment is copied over as an answer or something like that?

I guess there should be an option to the creator of the question to do this.

Comment: Try the search function! A [search for "+accept +answer +comment"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Baccept+%2Banswer+%2Bcomment) yields a lot of related question. Of particular interest is [this declined feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question) (possible duplicate), from the first page of search results. (I can post this as answer, but maybe it's more natural to close your question as a duplicate.)

Comment: I found unanswered questions, that are really answered in comments really annoying. Some moderators should be allowed to mark that type of comments as answers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is absolutely no need for a feature that allows you to mark a comment as an answer. In fact, that goes against one of the primary tenants of the site: questions and answers are the primary focus, while comments are just "noise".

The better solution is to simply leave an `@username` reply for that person, informing them that their comment actually answered your question and requesting that they post it as an answer so that you can accept it. I've seen this done numerous times (and had people do it with me), and my experience has been that users are more than happy to oblige.

If (and only if) they don't come back and post their comment as an answer within a reasonable frame of time (say, a few days) should you consider posting your *own* answer to the question, as [Mike suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments/90269#90269).

Answer (score 1):

Very closely related...

[How to Give Credit for An Answer in the Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63627/how-to-give-credit-for-an-answer-in-the-comments)

As an FYI, you can always [answer your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89333/whats-the-best-way-to-post-a-tutorial-on-so/89339#89339)

Answer (score 1):

If I come across this and it's a question that's not mine, I answer in Community Wiki and give credit to the person who answered it in comments. If it were my question, I would post an answer and probably wouldn't make it CW.