# My Question was "answered" in a comment, How do I close the question?

Tags: support, answers-as-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unanswered Question - Answered in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments)

Almost two months ago I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626785/find-all-references-to-a-specific-table-column-in-oracle-10g). My question was only *partially* answered, and only in the form of comments. One of which was a reference to a similar (but *not* actually a duplicate) questions. At this point there are no 'answers' to accept. The issue was resolved with the help of the comments (along with some other help).

I have tried to 'vote' to close the question, but I need 4 people to agree with me that my own question should be closed? (and the reasons for "closing" are not perfect fits...but 'duplicate' is 'close enough').

How do I "clean the books" of this question so that it is not sitting open and unanswered?

Comment: CharlesB's answer would be the best approach. Answer the question yourself and explain how the comments helped give you some of the information you needed but then expand on how you resolved it. That way it will remain so others can see it. You never know, it may be useful.

Comment: Just for future reference, what you're talking about is *accepting an answer* (and CharlesB is right about how to do that in this situation). Technically, on Stack Overflow, closing a question means that no new answers will be accepted. So you shouldn't actually *"close"* the question to indicate that it's been answered. Questions only get closed because they're bad, or because they're duplicates. Otherwise, we prefer to leave them open just in case someone else comes along later with an even better answer.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How should I handle questions which are answered in the comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54718/186664)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can answer yourself, and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Agreed. Also, make sure when you answer the question to clearly describe the solution to your problem, so that people looking for similar answers can quickly get what they need. And of course you should also credit the commenter who helped you arrive at the solution in your post, and make sure to +1 their comment! :D After all, it sure was nice of them to give you their rep points for the answer. ;)

Comment: I think the delay is related to the date the question was originally posted. After that time has expired it's possible to answer your own question and accept it immediately.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: Thanks for precision, updated

Comment: @Brian, I noticed that I didn't actually get "rep" for answering my own question.