# Got an answer to a bounty'd question, but it was in a comment. What to do?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to handle questions which are answered in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-to-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments)
>   [How to Give Credit for An Answer in the Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63627/how-to-give-credit-for-an-answer-in-the-comments)

I asked a question, and I didn't get an answer, so I put up a bounty. The best answer I got in response was actually written in a **comment**. A little later, someone else wrote a good answer as an answer. It was more complex than the comment answer and contained unnecessary parts, but still must have taken some work. I appreciate the effort, but it wasn't the best answer.

How should I handle the situation? I'm going to lose the rep points anyhow, so I might as well give them to someone. What is the right thing to do?

Here's the question in question: [Java & Windows 7: Reliably getting IPv4 netmask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299566/java-windows-7-reliably-getting-ipv4-netmask)

Comment: Comment asking the person to post their comment as an answer?

Comment: @J,  That looks suspiciously like an answer (in a comment) ;)

Comment: @Lix Oh, fine.  Answer posted.  :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle questions which are answered in the comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-to-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments), [Mark a comment as answer to a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question), [Unanswered Question - Answered in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments), [How to Give Credit for An Answer in the Comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63627/how-to-give-credit-for-an-answer-in-the-comments)

Answer (score 16):

Comment asking the person to post their comment as an answer.

Comment: This seems more like a comment :-D

Comment: @AdamRackis You people are so hard to please!

Comment: @AdamRackis: It would have been funnier if you could have convinced Lix to post that comment.

Comment: @an - and I almost did it too :P

Comment: That sounds great, although I'm not sure that user will notice my comment on their comment.  Is there a way to send a private message to another user?

Comment: @TimothyMiller: No, but you can include an @ Username to alert their inbox (Much at this message should have alerted you)