# Body links in meta are hidden in plain view in mobile at default size

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, design, ipad

Find the link(s) in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196527/how-to-deal-with-answers-provided-as-a-comment), opened at the default size in portrait mode on an iPad:

[image]

If I zoom in, the underlines appear, but then not all of the content is on the screen:

[image]

This happens the same way in both Chrome and Safari on iPad, but oddly only happens on links inside body text, not links in comments.

I would like to request that the link color be updated to have some semblance of contrast, and/or we stop using fancy dashed/dotted underlines and just do it the old-fashioned way.

Comment: Why aren't you using the mobile theme?

Comment: @Sha the mobile theme lacks multiple features, particularly as a moderator.

Answer (score -2):

The underlines of the link will appear when you zoom in, right ? I think that underlines didn't disappear in normal size but rather too small to display

Comment: This might fit as comment, not answer.

Comment: I just want to answer here. See if my answer get upvote or downvote and possibly get accepted. And that post seems didn't have any question. So how can I answer ?

Comment: You seem to miss the concept of feature request. The author of the question here is asking the team to implement a new feature. Proper answer might be from a team member who will either accept or reject the request, or ordinary user who can come up with a better idea or some guidelines to help the team implement the feature.